# Angularjs how to get data into specfic dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ive been trying to build a commenting system all day and just can't seem to get my head round a problem I'm having, I load in the comments with ng-repeat:

```
<ul class="list-group commentHolder list-unstyled" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    <li class="list-group-item">

    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{comment.commentcontent}}</p>
<div>

<a class="list-group-item-text" ng-click="showReply = ! showReply">Reply</a>
    <a class="list-group-item-text" ng-click="getReply({{commentid}})" >Show Replies</a>                        
</div>
.....
     </li>

<div class="replies" ng-repeat="reply in replies">
    {{reply.commentcontent}}
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

All comments and replies are in the same table with parentid for replies

I get back all replies with parentid passed in by the clicked comments id, the replies are put into a $scope.replies = data;

it will display the data but will have it under all comments.

I tried a few things but it doesn't seem to be a way to do it a "angularjs way".

I am unsure how to display the data just under the associated comment.

Any help would be great. Thanks

----- EDIT -------

```
 <li ng-repeat="reply in comment.replies">
    {{reply.commentcontent}}
 </li>
```

This is the function that adds to comment

```
$scope.test102 = function(comment)
{
var replies = {"commentid":9000, "commentcontent":"reply comment text test text"};
comment.replies = replies;
}
```

Now no values are being added into the ng-repeat for replies.

Any thoughts?
Thanks again.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? It seems the template is kinda messed up, at least I can see there is one additional `</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the replies are bound to the replies of the current comment in the ng-repeat loop. Currently it seems that you have a single $scope.replies that you repeat in the div:

```
<div class="replies" ng-repeat="reply in replies">
{{reply.commentcontent}}
</div>
```

If you change this:

```
<a class="list-group-item-text" ng-click="getReply({{commentid}})" >Show Replies</a>
```

to

```
<a class="list-group-item-text" ng-click="getReply(comment)" >Show Replies</a>
```

the getReply method should add the replies to comment that you pass as an argument.
Then you can bind to the comments replies like this:

```
<div class="replies" ng-repeat="reply in comment.replies">
{{reply.commentcontent}}
</div>
```

It looks like you expect the replies to be an array, but the test102 function adds a single object to comment.replies.

I have made a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4kqBmulJ1NhTnioEfK8s?p=preview) that shows what I mean

Comment: I think I've done what you suggested, I'm not getting the results I should be getting I'll post my code.